# Restoring multiple differential backups SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, restore

Over the bank holiday the backups failed on a db the full has been restored and now I have several differentials to be restored on top.

Could someone give best method or do I restore just sequentially one after the other in  T-SQL? Are there pitfalls that I should be aware of prior to doing  this.

Comment: You should only need to restore a single differential -- I suggest reading up on how differential backups work before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you do is restore the FULL backup, and then you restore the latest DIFF backup.  That's it!  This is assuming no FULL backups were taken in between the DIFF and the FULL you are restoring from (only exception is if you used a COPY_ONLY option in your full backup but most likely that wasn't the case). Remember to use WITH NORECOVERY on the full restore so you could continue to restore the DIFF.

In the rare exception that the DIFF throws an error stating that the LSN's don't match and your full backup is not the right one, you can query MSDB or right click on the DB, go to 'reports', and 'backup/restore' history.  That'll tell if a full backup was taken in between but by the sounds of it that is not the case.  On the DIFF restore make sure to state WITH RECOVERY to replay the log.

Comment: Thanks Guys  I hit the books and followed thru as I couldn't get to your site and guess what  they say the  same as you and it worked  beautifully and the nightly restores worked in  time for year end,   but I will check more thoroughly  though  I did spend a good while before asking ( this is only my 2nd question asked)

Comment: no problem, glad it helped.  Feel free to ask.  If you feel the answer was good to your questions you can mark them as answered so it shows in your profile and others can see.  Good luck with SQL Server.